# PhpQuery problems with changing the value with val()

Tags: php, phpunit, phpquery

I got a HTML table that looks like this:

```
<table id="xp">               
        <tbody >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="text" data-type="string" value="testvalue" class="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>  
</table>
```

Now I want to use phpQuery to change the value of the input like so:

```
require('**********/phpQuery.php');
$newsURL = "http://***********/index.php";
$newspage = file_get_contents($newsURL);

    if( $newspage )
    {           
      $pq = phpQuery::newDocument($newspage); 
                 foreach(pq('.text') as $stuffs)
                 {
                  $stuffs->val('ompalompa');
                  $this->assertEquals("ompalompa", $stuffs->val());
         }
             }
```

Am am using phpUnit assert to see the result but I just get this error:

```
//Call to undefined method DOMElement::val()
```

When I use the val() method to get the value from the first class element tho like this:

```
$stuffs = pq('.text')->val();
$this->assertEquals("testvalue", $stuffs);
```

It works fine and the assertion is passed

```
Time: 8 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

As i understand from the phpQuery manual val() without a parameter is just fetching the value fo the first element with the choosen selector and val() with a value sets the value of every element with the choosen selector as shown below. Can anyone explain to me wht the problem is if I am missunderstanding the documentation or if something else in my code is broken.

- val() Get the content of the value attribute of the first matched element.
- val($val) Set the value attribute of every matched element.

Comment: No I don't thik so, the $pq varialble and the pq method is not the same, the $pq variable is just storing the document it could be named anything, perhaps naming it $pq is a bit confusing tho.

Comment: Okey so it's some problem with the foreach because I can change the value of 1 item with a id, so it has to be a problem with how the object is returned in the foreach, any ideas?

Comment: Just printed out the result from $stuffs after the foreach and this is the results http://pastebin.com/qr7C73s0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs for phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/#ITERATE_IT), it states that when you loop with `foreach` a php DOM is returned. This must be passed back to phpQuery useing pq().

Change all occurances of `$stuffs` to `pq($stuffs)`

Out of curiosity I did the following as I have never used phpQuery before:

```
<?
require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
$html = "<table id=\"xp\">               
        <tbody >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type=\"text\" data-type=\"string\" value=\"testvalue\" class=\"text\">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type=\"text\" data-type=\"string\" value=\"\" class=\"text\">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>  
</table>";

$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($html); 
foreach(pq('.text') as $stuffs)
{
  pq($stuffs)->val('ompalompa');
  echo pq($stuffs)->val()."</br>";
}

?>
```

The output was:

```
ompalompa
ompalompa
```

If I use:

```
$stuffs->val('ompalompa');
```

Then

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::val() in /var/www/index.php on line 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce, The ";" was just missing from the example here, missed it in the copy process. and the phpQuery::selectDocument($pq); did not work I still get the same problem. The reason I dont have ids on them is because I didn't write the html, and have no acces to it directly. I have looked through the jquery docs and from that I wrote the code I posted here, I just can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: I edited the answer adding `Change $stuffs->val('ompalompa'); to pq($stuffs)->val('ompalompa');`

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't se the edit. Tried it but still get the same answer. but as I have said on the comments on my own post I think it's the DOM element getting returned from the foreach that is the problem, it looks like this pastebin.com/qr7C73s0

Comment: did you change `$this->assertEquals("ompalompa", pq($stuffs)->val());` as well?

Comment: yes, but the error is thrown on the code line above, i guess val() is not a legit function to edit data in the DOM Elemen Object, but if I type `echo $stuffs->getAttribute("value");`I get the value and I can set it by using `setAttribute("value", "ompalompa")`; but I dont get why I can't use val();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30922/discussion-between-james-birkett-and-user1593846)

Comment: @user1593846 I have rewritten the answer to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks alot man, I know that serAttribute is not a part of pq but I got it to work with that. Your solution was perfect and solved the problem. Thanks alot for the time and effort on this topc. saved my day!